# Parenthetical Names

Tags: code-golf, string, balanced-string

## Parenthetical names

Your challenge is to build a program that puts parentheses around the 'title' part of names. For example, `Sonic the Hedgehog` is converted to `Sonic (the Hedgehog)`.

#### Rules:

- **Around every `the` that passes the following rules, an opening parentheses will be added *before* the `the` and a corresponding closing parentheses will be added at the end of the string.**
- Inputs will only contain words (uppercase/lowercase letters and spaces).
- Trailing `the`s are ignored.
- With more than one `the`s in a row, every other `the` is parenthesized. (So `pig the the the hog hog hog` turns into `pig (the the (the hog hog hog))`.)
- Remaining `the`s are skipped unless surrounded by spaces. For example, the `the` in `their` would not be parenthesized.

##### I know this may seem lacking in detail. However, it's hard to get one set of really specific guidelines working- just follow the above rules and you're good.

Inspired by this xkcd comic: https://xkcd.com/2252/

This is `code-golf`, so least number of bytes wins.

Comment: Since it hasn't been said yet: we have the [Sandbox of proposed challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where challenges can be posted, reviewed, adjusted, and perfected based on feedback before it goes to main. Oh, and welcome to CGCC of course. :) If you clarify all the comments and add rules/test cases for them, the challenge can be reopened. As mentioned by @pxeger in the comment above: a challenge should be clear from the rules alone, and shouldn't be deducted/guessed based on test cases.

Comment: This seems clear to me now.  I've reopened it.  However a bunch of the answers are probably invalid.  If anyone wants to take it upon themselves to figure out which and inform their authors be my guest.  Invalid answers will be subject to deletion.

Comment: So, `the the the pig the the the` is unchanged, since all of the `the`s are leading and trailing?

Comment: Also please would you mind explaining the last text case?

Comment: @Neil The last test case is explicitly explained in the rules.

Comment: @WheatWizard So the mismatch in the number of `hog`s is a typo?

Comment: @Neil Ah yes.  Presumably that's a good observation.

Comment: Thanks @Neil. I just fixed that!

Comment: OK in that case I just need clarification on `the the the pig the the the` if you don't mind?

Comment: Sorry I've only just noticed your edit. For the last test case I was expecting either that it was unchanged or that it became `the the (the pig (the the the))`; would you mind explaining why it's neither?

Comment: true... that does make more sense. my idea was that the trailing `the`s would be treated as part of the group of words `pig the the the`, not parsed separately. but I can edit it if you think that's a better case.

Comment: I just need to know how many leading and trailing `the`s I should be ignoring, and that test case appears to be inconsistent, unless you can come up with an explanation for it.

Comment: @Neil yeah, that's an error. Every other `the` is skipped so it results in almost what you said.

Comment: Still not quite getting it I'm afraid - I don't see how `pig the the hog` turns into `pig (the the hog)` but `pig the the the` turns into `pig the (the the)` while still allowing `pig the hog the pig` to turn into `pig (the hog (the pig))`...

Comment: The `pig the the the` in the last case is `pig the (the the))` because of the number of `the`s before it. Again, every other `the` is skipped, not counting the first one. By itself, `pig the the the` is transformed into `pig (the the the)`.

Comment: If `the the the pig the the the` becomes `the the (the pig the (the the))`... presumably this means that `pig the hog the the the` becomes `pig (the hog the (the the))` and `pig the hog the pig` becomes `pig (the hog the pig)`... or is there something I'm missing again?

Comment: You're right. I'm going to make this more simple. Thanks so much, though- I wouldn't have spotted those errors on my own. When I asked this I didn't have super specific rules in my mind.

Comment: Just need one final check... `the the the pig` becomes `the (the the pig)` or `the the (the pig)`?

Comment: It would become `the (the the pig)`.

Comment: You just said that `the the the pig` becomes `the (the the pig)`, but in the last test case it becomes `the the (the pig)`. Is there a reason behind this? According to the rules you set, I don't think the rest of the string should have any affect on how the beginning is handled, so they should be the same.

Answer (score 4):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 27 bytes

```apl
\b(the )+
 (the .*)
&
 (\1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/z8mSaMkI1VBU5tLAczQ09LkUgOyYww1//8HCRRkpnMBsUJGPoQGiaGxFWDq0PkwNVDx/486FwIA)

`\b(the )+` replace multiple `the`s with:
…`&` themselves

`(the .*)` replace a space followed by `the` and everything until the end with:
… `(\1)` a space followed by the parenthesised text

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 27 bytes

```
+`(?<!\bthe) (the .+)
 ($1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fO0HD3kYxJqkkI1VTQQNIKuhpa3IpaKgYav7/D@IWZKZzgWgYG4gVMvIhNEgMja2ArAeZD1MDFQcA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Parenthesises from all  `the` s to the end of the line, unless the  `the`  follows a previous `the`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
≔⪪Ｓ θ≔⌕Ａθtheη≔⁻η⁺⊕η⟦⁰⊖Ｌθ⟧η⪫Ｅθ⁺×№ηκ(ι ⭆η)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwEETv/YrQ0wYqePdUFKGiUKg38VDakCymSdqk/n7c1GoPSZa82ZnpVDt1ttUxlt6jNNA4jQEq4@bQhAmNBF6wnOV0j/yQraozmr7UGkZiQYlE1UZvaGYPqmC1prcy3SQGYYLoQZHwsS/YSWx/V2FkUDBy/uSrT03BAS4Wyat1KWVxuuMgPBztTJDcX6kZpGzka8n/7rd7WiZhzhOJkZqydBxK9puVXeYs7t76Aw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪Ｓ θ
```

Split the input on spaces.

```
≔⌕Ａθtheη
```

Find all the indices of `the`.

```
≔⁻η⁺⊕η⟦⁰⊖Ｌθ⟧η
```

Remove any index that's `1` more than another index, and `0` and the last index (because those `the`s weren't surrounded by spaces).

```
⪫Ｅθ⁺×№ηκ(ι
```

Prefix `(` to the remaining indices and join with spaces.

```
⭆η)
```

Output the matching `)`s at the end.

A port of @Steffan's Python answer is also 40 bytes:

```
⪫⪪⪫⪪Ｓ the ¦ (the ¦the (the¦the the×)№ＫＡ(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPI7ggJxOF6ZlXUFoSXAJUka6hqaOgpFCSkaqgBGZpwJkgBogH54DZmtZcEJNDMnNTizWUNJV0FJzzS4ECAamp2Y45OWADgeJAlf//Q7UpFGSmK8DYGflgNtd/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⪫⪪⪫⪪Ｓ the ¦ (the ¦the (the¦the the
```

Substitute  `the`  with  `(the`  and `the (the` with `the the`.

```
×)№ＫＡ(
```

Output enough `)`s to match the number of `(`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 93 bytes

```
lambda s,t='the',r=' (',w=' ':(p:=s.replace(w+t+w,r+t+w).replace(t+r+t,t+w+t))+p.count(r)*')'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVFLDoIwEI1bT9HERTu2sjYkvYkuEEFIUJpSQjyLGxKjd9J7uLeET9pSuujnzXvzZqaPt7irrLy1z5QfXrVKd_vPsYiup3OEKqY4VlmCmeQYEcwafeCQiJBXgUxEEcUJaaiiDZPdDhOoqAaYhqgCoCKIy_qmiIQtBtybfFc_IXMNpqSzQCK_YADkrg2aouuJr18oK5f4Y9Tmd1k8moFPhjD4Vcip0FH1F42AqV_QGl1ZUo-zp2bT2VPzCHumOXjOp2mgrqutWXQduszl3FdnsKP977dtf_4B)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 31 bytes

```
⌈D‛λλÞIf$L‹o:›Fꜝλ\(p;VṄ:\(O\)*J
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLijIhE4oCbzrvOu8OeSWYkTOKAuW864oC6Ruqcnc67XFwocDtW4bmEOlxcKE9cXCkqSiIsIiIsInRoZSB0aGUgcGlnIHRoZSB0aGUgaG9nIHRoZSJd)

Port of Charcoal answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„ €€ÀDć'(©«ì:…€€ (8∍D®K:D®¢')×«
```

Port of [*@Steffan*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248426/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8hUdNa4DocIPLkXZ1jUMrD60@vMbqUcMyiLCChsWjjl6XQ@u8rYDEoUXqmoenH1r9/39BZrpCSUaqQkY@hIbyAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/0cN8xQeNa0BosMNLkfa1TUOrTy0@vAaq0cNyyDCChoWjzp6XQ6t87YCEocWqWsenn5o9X@d/yUZqQoFmelcQKwAZIPpjHw4H8wG0WjqQOJwMXQ@TA1MP7IemHqoWhR1MDaSGFZ7YWaguQUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
            :  # Replace all
„ €€À          # " the ":
„ €€           #  Push dictionary string "  the"
    À          #  Rotate it once towards the right: " the "
     Dć'(©«ì  '# with " (the ":
     D         #  Duplicate the " the "
      ć        #  Extract the head
       '(     '#  Push "("
         ©     #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
          «    #  Append it to the extracted space
           ì   #  Merge it in front of the remaining string: " (the "

          :    # Then replace all
…€€ (8∍        # "the (the":
…€€ (          #  Push dictionary string "the ("
     8∍        #  Extend it to size 8: "the (the"
       D®K     # with "the the":
       D       #  Duplicate the "the (the"
        ®K     #  Remove the `®` ("("): "the the"

D              # Duplicate the resulting string
 ®¢            # Pop the copy, and count the amount of `®` ("(") in it
   ')×        '# Pop and push a string with that many ")"
      «        # Append it at the end of the string
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `„ €€` is `"  the"` and `…€€ (` is `"the ("`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 116 bytes:

```py
import re
f=lambda x,c=0:re.sub(f'(?<{"!="[c]}e) the {["","[^t]"][c]}[\w\W]+',lambda x:f' ({f(x.group()[1:],1)})',x)
```

Comment: `["","[^t]"][c]` => `"[^t]"*c`